# Spring, Hibernate, MySQL stress test

Tags: spring, hibernate, c3p0

While stress testing my web application, it seems [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) can no longer create a connection to the database.

The web application is developed using [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) 3.0, Hibernate 3.6, and c3p0 0.9.2.1 connection pooling. It runs under [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) 7. The DBMS is MySQL Server 5.5. All the transaction are managed by Spring via the `@Transactional` annotation.

The following are some of the settings of Hibernate/c3p0

```
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="15" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="75" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="100" /> 
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600" />   
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="2500" /> 
    <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="true" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />      
    <property name="defaultTimeout" value="15" />
    </bean>
```

This is the JDBC connection URL:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://myserver:myport/mydb?connectTimeout=31000&socketTimeout=30000
```

When I reach around 200 concurrent users, the CPU load goes near 100% (but the connection pool seems still under 75) and the following exception occurs:

```
 SEVERE: Cannot connect to database.
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransa
 ctionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connec
 tion
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
         at com.my-company.SimpleConnetionLogFilter.doFilter(SimpleConnetionLogFilter.java:132)
         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
         at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org
 .hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
         at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
         at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
         at com.my-company.bizlogic.spring.XService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4e6a04f7.digest(<generated>)
         at com.my-company.XController.handleRequest(XController.java:55)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
         ... 24 more
 Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
         at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
         at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
         at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
         at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
         at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
         at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
         at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
         at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
         at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:551)
         ... 35 more
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
         at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
         at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77)
         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:687)
         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
         at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
         at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
         ... 39 more
 Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@7624a28d -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1416)
         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
         ... 42 more
```

What I clearly do not understand yet is what happens when all the 75 connections in the pool are used?

I thought that the next transaction will wait for one free connection.

And since I have set the *defaultTimeout* for transactions I expected this to happen in this case. This kind of error will be managed in the application and the client will know that the server is busy. But currently a generic "Server Internal Error" is generated, because on the Tomcat side it seems like MySQL is no more reachable, not just busy.

Moreover, am I missing something in the settings? I have already tried to raise some of the Hibernate/c3p0 and JDBC parameters, but the only effect is that I get a different Exception, always related to the JDBC connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the c3p0 parameter checkoutTimeout set, and you are either exhausting your pools via a Connection leak, or you are just pushing them very hard, so that some clients fail to acquire a Connection within the checkoutTimeout period.

Ways to deal:

1) Make sure you aren't leaking Connections. try setting unreturnedConnectionTimeout and debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces (see [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients))

2) If there is no Connection leak, configure your DataSource better so that it can deal with your load. First, try increasing [numHelperThreads](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#numHelperThreads), make significantly bigger than the number of cores on which you are running (since these Threads are often held up on IO with the database). Next, try a larger maxPoolSize. You might also reconfigure statement pooling. For simplicity, I'd turn it off until you resolve this issue (set maxStatements to zero). When Connection pooling is working well, you can turn it back on, but Statements of 100 is way to few to handle 200-ish Connections, you'll unproductively churn through PreparedStatements. Consider using [maxStatementsPerConnection](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxStatementsPerConnection) instead of maxStatements. Set its value to about the number of PreparedStatements frequently used by application clients.

3) If your DataSource still can't promptly handle the load, accept a longer [checkoutTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#checkoutTimeout) (or set checkoutTimeout to zero so that clients never time out).

Unrelatedly... are you sure you want [autoCommitOnClose](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#autoCommitOnClose) set to true?

Good luck!

Comment: Thinking that Spring will not create connections leaks (always use @Transactional), I just skipped the first point.

The "Cannot connect to DB" has gone away, by increasing the numHelperThreads to 10 (the test is running on two cores CPU). At the same time I also increased the values of initialPoolSize (30), acquireIncrement (10) and maxPoolSize (100).
Thank you!

Comment: "autoCommitOnClose" was there to test MySQL connector fail-over in case of replication (1 Master- N Slaves), which is another issue I should investigate further.

Answer (score 3):

We discovered a similar issue during a simple load test of our application (NON JTA). We changed the connection release mode and this solved our issue. Hope it does for you:

Hibernate property 
hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction

Comment: Thank you, following Steve Waldan's suggestions I solved the problem, but I will investigate further on which is the best connection release_mode for my application.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I struggled with my application not releasing connections for a whole day until I saw this solution.  After I made this change everything worked great, thanks a bunch!